# How to login to my second router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bridge

I have two routers, one ADSL router(A) which is connected to the phone line another wireless router(B) connected to this ADSL router. I connect my PC, laptop, mobiles to router B .  like this:

[image: image from pcwintech.com]

I can login [ admin panel ] to router B by accessing 10.0.0.1 , and earlier I could login to router A as well by accessing 192.168.1.1 . But one day I logged in to router A and changed this to bridge mode and changed the settings in router B to use PPPoE . I can connect to internet using router B, but somehow I can't login to router A anymore. ( infact I can't even ping 192.168.1.1 ).

I want to change my router A from bridge mode to normal one. How can I do that when I can't even login to this router. Moreover if I connect laptop directly to router A even then nothing happens neither I can connect to router nor I can access the internet.

Router B:  Netgear WNR1000v2
Router A: TKD 318-EUI [ I got this router from ISP ]

[image]

Please let me know if any other information is required as well.

Answer (score 1):

The *direct* answer to this question, is (drum roll)...

In **bridged mode** the *access* `IP` moves from `192.168.1.1` **to** `192.168.100.1` (note that it's **100** now. *Not* **1**).

Use that (new) address in your web browser, and you'll see that familiar configuration again. Well, after the *Login*.

Comment: Is this brand specific ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reset the router following the manufacturer's directions. It usually involves removing power, holding down the reset button, and then applying power. You cannot log in to a bridge because it has no address.

However, if you do want to use two routers for some reason, you should set one of them to bridging mode. Why do you want to change?

Comment: Earlier none of my router were in bridge mode and I was able to access internet too. I got to know that if you have to do port forwarding and you have two routers then one router needs to be in BRIDGE mode. No idea how true is that. But anyways now I just want to revert back to that earlier setting means No bridge mode.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a paperclip to push the Reset button on the back of the router.

The 30/30/30 rule is recommended.

Hold the Reset button for 30 seconds, power off (unplug) the router, continue holding the Reset button for another 30 seconds, and then plug the router back in while continuing to hold the Reset button for an additional 30 seconds.

Afterwards, you can then release the Reset button. Give the router a few minutes to boot up, and then you should be able to access it with factory default settings.